# Relative UI unit in QT Widgets QSS stylesheets

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qtstylesheets

My current UI doesn't use QT widgets paint and it's mostly done with QSS markup. The current styles are defined in pixels and I could not find anything in the QT documentation that allows the styles to be defined as relative unit as opposed to pixels. I would like to know if it's possible to use something relative then tie that unit to a ROOT font-size. In case I need to adjust for a particular screen size like a battery charger IOT device that has a small screen, while my main UI was designed for very large screens (27 inch monitor). So instead of me styling a button just for the IOT device, I shrink the base unit (technique similar to web responsive like REM) then everything like fonts, padding, buttons shrink proportionally. Is that something that QT supports?

Comment: There is rudimentary support in Qt style sheets for relative units like `em`: Try setting your QApplication font and watch as a 1em border varies in thickness. I didn't find a documentation about size units in the Qt style sheet docs.

Comment: @MartinHennings but that unit is dependent on parent right? Em on the Web is too funky, because of dependency.  There is nothing like points? something that I can scale based on font-size so everything increases/shrinks?

Comment: You should start by specifying which unit you'd like to relate to: Screen resolution? Display DPI? System font size? System scaling?

Comment: Ideally, I would use all abstract units that are tied to a default font size in PT. So I create my fonts as heading styles, then my container sizes and everything is a percentage of that default unit. Then based on screen resolution I can adjust these units independently. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html But this is QT GUI and not Widgets. The point system if possible could take care of the scalability.

Comment: I built 3 sized buttons in my UI design software (used virtual pixel as base unit) that are good enough for most GUIs to be used in any screen size if proportion is maintained https://i.imgur.com/OipC8X4.png. Then it's a matter of minor adjustment if needed. But the EM unit as I said is a no-no, because it causes inheritance issues. I don't want a button's size to depend on another parent's size, that becomes messy.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge vanilla `Qt Widgets` don't support free scaling at all. Recently high-DPI display support was added, but it only scales in fixed ratios (e.g. 1:2). There are other options to get scaling in Qt applications:

- Use QML (didn't try this yet myself, but it's developed with adaption to different displays in mind)
- Use `QGraphicsScene` with `QGraphicsWidget`
- Use `QGraphicsScene` with custom graphics objects that implement the behavior you need
- Roll your own widgets

I'd love to stand corrected on this answer - maybe in a future Qt version...?

Comment: How difficult and messy is to migrate or use both widgets and qml?

Comment: I've not yet seen that in action (theoretically it's possible). Maybe ask a separate question? But I don't see the benefit of it to your problem. Maybe you should include more specific information in your question, e.g. why you need to use widgets at all?

Comment: 5 years or more invested in building a complex application with current clients using it disconnected from the internet (IOT device)